# How does "Category Theory as a Conceptual Tool in the Study of Cognition" explain the intuitions behind adjoint functors

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, adjoint-functors

There is a book *Logical Foundations of Cognition* edited by John MacNamara and Gonzalo Reyes (OUP, 1994). This contains a chapter "Category Theory as a Conceptual Tool in the Study of Cognition" by François Magnan and Reyes. If I remember correctly, the chapter introduces category theory to cognitive scientists, and does so by emphasising the intuitions behind constructs, avoiding formal notation. I believe the chapter explained left and right adjoints, possibly by using diagrams of Galois connections in which 2-d shapes were mapped (for example) to the smallest subset of a grid that would enclose them. I'd be grateful if anyone who has read this could remind me what the examples were, and what is said about adjoints and adjunctions.

This is for a paper on category theory and semiotics, wherein I need to explain some ideas to artists and other non-mathematicians. I don't have access to the library where I once read the book, and as it's around £50, am reluctant to buy it for just one paper. I can't find an open-access copy of book or chapter, and although I've contacted Reyes and his university, haven't had a reply. The other editor, MacNamara, died in 1996. I've also not been able to unambiguously identify Magnan.

Once upon a time, the entire chapter could be viewed in Google Books. But no longer.

Comment: the £50 are worth the investment, don't you believe?

Comment: @janmarqz For one paper? I would say absolutely not.

Comment: It would be for two papers. There was also one by Lawvere, "Tools for the advancement of objective logic: closed categories and toposes", which I enjoyed. But even so, £25 each? I agree with the tweet at https://twitter.com/DonnachaDCU/status/1407980097689239552 . How can these authors justify not making their work free? It's not as if they'll be earning huge royalties by now.

Comment: put it on a balance: if that money produces you earn more, invest; if not ...etc

Comment: https://libgen.is/search.php?req=Logical+Foundations+of+Cognition&lg_topic=libgen&open=0&view=simple&res=25&phrase=1&column=def

Comment: @MorganRodgers, this is unhelpful. You say that if I want to know what the paper is about, I can read it. Did you not see my paragraph 2, where I explain why I can't get hold of it? And (sorry zeta zero), it has been made illegal to access Libgen (and SciHub) in the UK. You also wrote that it is not about maths as within the scope of the Help Centre. But the Help Centre says "We welcome questions about: Understanding mathematical concepts and theorems." My question is about understanding adjoint functors. If I'm right about the content, an answer will help people who read it do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two examples of adjoints.
The first takes place on a rectangular grid. The functor on figures $F \mapsto \cup \text{\{all squares intersecting F\}}  $ is left adjoint to $F \mapsto \cup\text{\{all squares inside F\}}$. The first is interpreted as "squares possibly in $F$", whereas the second is "squares necessarily contained in $F$".

[image]

The second example is $((A,B)\mapsto A+B) \dashv (X \mapsto (X,X)) \dashv ((A,B)\mapsto A \times B).$

Then the standard definition of adjunction is given via bijection of hom-sets.

Comment: Thanks very much. You must have read the entire chapter: do you think it helps explain the notion of adjoint functor to the intended audience. This long ago, I can't remember how much knowledge the reader was assumed to have.

Comment: @Phil van Kleur  There is nothing on adjoints except what I mentioned, so I know as much as you about the usefulness of such an approach. For non-math people the examples look pretty good to my eyes, but I myself can't claim to have deep insights into adjoints in the context of logic, or into ways to teach math to non-mathematicians.

Comment: Thanks anyway. I think I can construct some nice intuitions for non-maths people from that, and you've saved me spending £50 on a copy of the book. If I may say so, more helpful than the moderator who decided a closed or deleted question would be more useful to me than an actual answer. And, I really can't understand this, who said I should read the paper myself, not ask someone else to do so. What! At the cost of £50??? I suspected I'd catch a sufficiently wide audience that someone in it would have already read the paper and not mind writing a few lines, and so it was. So thanks again.